# Objective-C How does snapchat make the text on top of an image/video so sharp and not pixelated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, snapchat

In my app, it allows users to place text on top of images like snapchat, then they are allowed to save the image to their device. I simply add the text view on top of the image and take a picture of the image using the code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.layer.bounds.size);
[imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage* savedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But when I compare the text on my image, to the text from a snapchat image...it is significantly different. Snapchat's word text on top of image is significantly sharper then mine. Mine looks very pixelated. Also I am not compressing the image at all, just saving the image as is using ALAssetLibrary.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, it defaults to a 1x scale (i.e. non-retina resolution). You probably want:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.layer.bounds.size, YES, 0);
```

Which will use the same scale as the screen (probably 2x). The final parameter is the scale of the resulting image; 0 means "whatever the screen is".

Comment: +1 Worth noting though that the last parameter is the `scale`, where `0` means "use the device's main screen scale factor"

Answer (score 0):

If your imageView is scaled to the size of the screen, then I think your jpeg will also be limited to that resolution.  If setting the scale on UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions does not give you enough resolution, you can do your drawing in a larger offscreen image.  Something like:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imageSize.width,imageSize.height)];
CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),scale,scale);
[textOverlay.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You need to set the "scale" value to scale the textOverlay view, which is probably at screen size, to the offscreen image size.

Alternatively, probably simpler, you can start with a larger UIImageView, but put it within another UIView to scale it to fit on screen.  Do the same with your text overlay view.  Then, your code for creating composite should work, at whatever resolution you choose for the UIImageView.